# NSPredicate compare dates in CoreData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a managed object with two dates: dateOne and dateTwo and I want to retrieve the dates where dateTwo is older than dateOne.

Right now I am using the following predicate to fetch the objects:

```
NSArray *objects = nil;

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Object" inManagedObjectContext:context];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dateOne > dateTwo", @""];

objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
[request release];
```

Sometimes it works, but other times the objects fetched have a dateTwo that is more recent than dateOne. Is there a better way to do something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could add a BOOL property "dateTwoIsOlder" to the entity, then just fetch objects that adhere to that?

Comment: That is a great idea. Thank you! :)

Comment: works, but probably not the best idea as now you have to worry about that bool getting out of sync. you also don't want to make it a transient property since all objects will be have to loaded in memory to process the request. Should be a predicate format that up ports this, looking around the interwebs now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a `fetch request` from core data and not do it programmatically?